# Display a continuing progress bar in notification, android?

Tags: android, notifications, progress-bar

I am trying to display a indeterminate progress bar in the notification window. But it is not displayed.

This is my code

```
                    int id = 1;
                NotificationManager mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                        MenuActivity.this);
                mBuilder.setContentTitle("My app")
                        .setContentText("Download in progress");
                mBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, true);
                // Issues the notification
                mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
```

I am following this link
[Continuing Activity Indicator](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/display-progress.html#ActivityIndicator)

Can someone guide me out what's wrong?

Comment: *public Notification.Builder setProgress (int max, int progress, boolean indeterminate)

**Added in API level 14*** what is you device API level? ... NotificationCompat is not adding the newer features of Notification on older API

Comment: How do you make it non cancelable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

solved only needed to add an icon

```
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
```